# Connect to MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2012, connectivity

I'm busy setting up a MS SQL Server instance on a Windows Server

The server is Windows Server 2012 R2 and the version of MS SQL Server is 2014 Essentials.

I've installed MS SQL and created my database, I've also installed HeidiSQL to test making connections to the server.

All this software is running off of the same machine.

When I run the MS SQL Management studio it connects to

```
Server name    : SPKWINVMSERVER\SQLSERV
Authentication : Windows Authentication
```

So I've tried to create a login using the management studio

right click Security > New  > Login

and I've created the login as

```
Login name : mssqladmin
password   : #FongKong123
```

I gave this user all the server roles for testing and it seemed to create ok.

However when I try to connect to it using this Login I've just created using HeidiSQL it fails

The connection details I'm using in HeidiSQL to connect are

```
Network type : Microsoft SQL Server (TCP/IP)
Hostname     : SPKWINVMSERVER\SQLSERV
User         : mssqladmin
Password     : #FongKong123
Port         : 1433
```

The above connection seems to work when connecting to the SQL Server on the server itself.

If trying to connect with another computer on the network (also using HeidiSQL) I imagine I won't be able to use SPKWINVMSERVER\SQLSERV as the hostname but it doesn't work on IP address which is in this case 192.168.20.67

```
Network type : Microsoft SQL Server (TCP/IP)
Hostname     : 192.168.20.67\SQLSERV
User         : mssqladmin
Password     : #FongKong123
Port         : 1433
```

What did I miss?

Comment: Do you have SqlServer authentication enabled? Go to the instance->properties->security to check it

Comment: The server authentication is set to SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode

Comment: I've updated to include instance name (PS they are both running off the same machine)

Comment: Go to HeidiSQL -> security and look for the new login. Maybe you didn't map it to the DB.

Comment: Ok so the only other change I made was to change 127.0.0.1\SQLSERV to SPKWINVMSERVER\SQLSERV and that made it work but that is a problem in itself because how would I do it from a remote computer using an IP address

Comment: @Trent, In client machine open RUN command , Type there mstsc, Then remote desktop connection window will open , type there your remote server ip there then connect. After that it will ask to server certificate, click yes. Then you shall able to login in your remote Server. Note:- If you are in Domain environment then check your user credetial for that server.

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan The Remote Desktop Connection worked but I will need to connect to the server using code at a later stage so I won't be able to use Remote Desktop

Answer (score 1):

Go to Sql Server Configuration Manager, and check on your client protocols if TCP/IP is enabled.

Comment: TCP/IP is enabled in the Server Configuration Manager

Comment: @Trent Firewall? is telnet working?

Comment: The firewall is disabled atm, I tried to telnet 192.168.20.67:1433 and it failed with a could not open connection error

Answer (score 1):

I believe I've found the reason this wasn't working, it seems none of the traffic was targeting port 1433.

To fix it I had to run the SQL Server Configuration Manager and then do the following

Navigate to TCP/IP under SQL Server Network Configuration > Protocols for SQLSERV

Right click TCP/IP and select Properties

Under the IP Addresses tab I had to add 1433 to TCP Port for all of the available IP Protocols

seems to be working ok now, thank you to everyone though for helping me get that far though

Comment: Thanks for updating.  If you can mark this as the answer, that would definitely help everyone out in the future.  I've run into this very problem/solution a few times over the years.